# Run apache as different user for different domains

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a server that is running multiple websites using vhosts, but I want each site to run under a different user/group and wondering if anyone knows how to do this in apache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Apache-ITK](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/), peruser or separate intsansy Apache.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions for that. I do use apache2-mpm-itk which allows me to define specific domains to run under specific users/groups. Works really well and it's easy to set up.